# std::u32string::erase error : no instance of overloaded function

Tags: c++, gcc

I want to remove a character from `std::u32string`, for example, I want to remove `|` from `U"abd|def"`

```
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::u32string a = U"abd|def";
    a.erase(std::remove(a.begin(), a.end(), U'|'), a.end());
}
```

The code works on my MacBook(Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)) without any error. How ever, an error comes up when I try to compile it on a Linux using gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0. The error message is

```
no instance of overloaded function "std::__cxx11::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::erase [with _CharT=char32_t, _Traits=std::char_traits<char32_t>, _Alloc=std::allocator<char32_t>]" matches the argument listC/C++(304)

m.cpp(6, 7): argument types are: (int, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<char32_t *, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char32_t, std::char_traits<char32_t>, std::allocator<char32_t>>>)

m.cpp(6, 7): object type is: std::u32string
```

How can I make the same code work on GCC?

Comment: You forgot to `#include <algorithm>` for this version of  [`std::remove`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove). Compiler sees only the [`std::remove`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/remove) from `<cstdio>` and tries to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `std::remove()` but did not `#include <algorithm>` - add that and it will compile.

Side note: with GCC 10+ you can enable C++20 and do it more simply:

```
std::erase(a, U'|');
```